# Delete all the records in table in iphone sdk with sqlite3

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

**EDITED:-** This is what i had implements:-

```
- (void) Delete_LoginData {
    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "DELETE FROM Login";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }       
    }
}
```

I want to delete all the rows from the database in one click.I had implemented the below methods:-

```
- (void) Delete_LoginData {
        sqlite3 *database;
        if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            const char *sql = "DELETE * FROM Login";
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;

            statement = [self PrepareStatement:sql];    
          //  int a1 = sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, 1);

            sqlite3_step(statement);
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }       
    }

    -(sqlite3_stmt*) PrepareStatement:(const char *)sql{
        // Setup the database object
        sqlite3 *database;
        // Init the animals Array

        // Open the database from the users filessytem
        if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
            const char *sqlStatement = sql;
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement,-1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                //NSLog(@"COMPILED STATEMENT: %@",compiledStatement);
                return compiledStatement;

            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

But it not working.
I am getting 0X0 for this statement = [self PrepareStatement:sql];
in delete_logindata method.

How to solve this.
Is there any solution regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Please change your method like:

```
- (void) Delete_LoginData
{
        sqlite3 *database;
        if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *sql = "DELETE FROM Login";
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
             if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
             {
               sqlite3_step(statement);
             }       
         }
}
```

In your code you are opening the database twice. In the second method you are opening a database that was already opened !
I don't know it is the actual issue or not, but I'll suggest don't do this.

Comment: Midhun what is sqlStatement over here?

Comment: @shweta: sorry, I edited my answer. I just copied your code, I forgot to change that variable :)

Comment: @shweta: still have the issue ?

Comment: Midhun yes still i am having problem.The data is not geting deleted

Comment: @shweta: did you changed the quesry and method

Comment: i had edited my question and write the mehtod which i had implemented

Comment: use `sqlite3_step(statement);` instead of `sqlite3_reset(statement);` .Surely it'll work

Answer (score 1):

write `const char *sql = "DELETE FROM Login"`; instead of `const char *sql = "DELETE * FROM Login";`

Answer (score 1):

change your const char*sql

```
const char *sql = "DELETE * FROM Login";
```

change above with this

```
const char *sql = "DELETE FROM Login";
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what will be correct answer for it. 
But I can suggest u this link  http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-SDK-Database-Insert-Update-Delete-with-SQLite-and-Objective-C-C-How-To   may be it will help u.